# loop through list that is returned from a method until the method gives me no records

Tags: c#

The `Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList();` returns 20 transactions at a time. I need to loop through it until it returns me no transactions at all.

I have the following code and I don't think it's efficient:

```
    IEnumerable<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> readings = Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList();;
    var gpsreadings = new List<TruckGpsReading>();

    do
    {
      gpsreadings = new List<TruckGpsReading>();
      if (readings.Count() > 0)
      {
        foreach (var reading in readings)
        {
          Logging.Log("Starting ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading 3", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
          var gpsreading = new TruckGpsReading();
          gpsreading.DateTimeOfReading = reading.DateTimeOfReading;
          gpsreading.Direction = reading.Direction;
          gpsreading.DriverNumber = CurrentIniSettings.DriverNumber;
          gpsreading.Latitude = (float)reading.Latitude;
          gpsreading.Longitude = (float)reading.Longitude;
          gpsreading.Speed = reading.Speed;
          gpsreading.TruckNumber = CurrentIniSettings.TruckNumber;
          gpsreadings.Add(gpsreading);
        }

        var response = client.SaveGpsReadings(globalSetting.TokenId, globalSetting.SourceId, gpsreadings.ToArray());
        if (response != "true")
        {
          Logging.Log("ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading: " + response, "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
        }
        else
        {
          Logging.Log("ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading: Reading.DeleteGpsReadings(readings)", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
          SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading.DeleteGpsReadings(readings);    
        }
      }
      readings = Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList();

    } while (readings.Count() > 0);
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

** EDIT ********

```
public static IEnumerable<Reading> GetUnProcessReadings()
{
  try
  {
    using (var context = new SuburbanEntities())
    {
      return (from r in context.Readings
             where r.IsPublished == false
             select r).Take(10).ToList();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.Log("An error occurred.", "GetPpsSetting", Apps.ServicesConfig, ex);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `Reading.GetUnProcessReadings()` return?

Comment: Without access to the Reading class we don't know how to answer this.

Comment: Sorry, I added it. People gotta learn to read minds :P

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you create a thread or background worker that check for Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList(); on regular interval, and when there is something in the list, sends an event with the current list; so you process the list every time the event occurs.

Comment: you get 20 items in readings and then in dowhile loop you want to assing the new variable gpsreading each value from readings and delete each readings item ?

Comment: @Jegan The database is populated from another program so I don't have any events to fire off to trigger a read. I am calling this method with a timer every X seconds to see if there is anything to process.

Comment: @terrybozzio Yes. I read in the table. Process 20 transactions, then remove them. I need to do this until there are none left.

Comment: @ErocM you do not have to access the other program. in your program create a background worker that check s for the available count on regular interval, if there is something then fire the event from the background worker to your main thread and process the data.

Answer (score 3):

From the code provided it's hard to find an optimal solution, but...

Don't see serious problems with the code, as is it's now, except a couple of suggessions:

1. use `while (readings.Count() > 0) {}`, and not `do/while`, because already on first request there *may* be no readings to parse.
2. If you are able to change the code inside `Reading.GetUnProcessReadings()`, this could be an option to look on using [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx). So you will avoid unnecessary `ToList(..)` call, so new `List<T>` generation every time, and will avoid `while` loop at all, just will use `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of everything being in a DoWhile, why not just put an if statement at the end of your foreach loop that basically reads

```
if(readings.count() <=0)
{
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Reading.GetUnProcessReadings()` gives you something iterable, which it probably does since `.ToList()` is typically something you do when you want to create an `IEnumerable`, why not just iterate over it?

Something more or less like this:

```
public void MyBigWrapperMethod()
{
    var gpsreadings = new List<TruckGpsReading>();
    foreach (var reading in Reading.GetUnProcessReadings())
    {
        Logging.Log("Starting ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading 3", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
        var gpsreading = new TruckGpsReading();
        gpsreading.DateTimeOfReading = reading.DateTimeOfReading;
        gpsreading.Direction = reading.Direction;
        gpsreading.DriverNumber = CurrentIniSettings.DriverNumber;
        gpsreading.Latitude = (float)reading.Latitude;
        gpsreading.Longitude = (float)reading.Longitude;
        gpsreading.Speed = reading.Speed;
        gpsreading.TruckNumber = CurrentIniSettings.TruckNumber;
        gpsreadings.Add(gpsreading);
    }

    var response = client.SaveGpsReadings(globalSetting.TokenId,
     globalSetting.SourceId, gpsreadings.ToArray());
    if (response == "true")
    {
        // do stuff if it works
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff if it doesn't work
    }
}
```

Also, there's a very good chance that the `SaveGpsReadings` method of the `client` object doesn't really need the last argument to be converted to `Array` form. Consider rewriting that, if you can, to something that takes a collection of `TruckGpsReading` objects.

Going even farther than that, are you sure you need to save all the GPS readings at once in a batch like that? Is there a way to save them one at a time? Then you can have something like

```
client.SaveSingleGpsReading (globalSetting.TokenId, globalSetting.SourceId, gpsreading);
```

right inside the loop.

The main thing I'm getting at is that you seem to be thinking in terms of getting a collection of stuff, massaging it into a different collection type, running a process on the whole collection, and massaging the output of *that* into a *different* collection type... when the efficient thing to do would be to pull an input, do what you need to with it, send it to output, and repeat.

**Don't keep a gigantic buffer of data when you don't have to.** Then the issue of how to manage all the collections becomes moot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing through event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BackgroundWorkerExample
{
public class Program
{
    private event EventHandler<EventArgs<List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading>>> ReadingAvailable;

    protected virtual void OnReadingAvailable(List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> list)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs<List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading>>> handler = ReadingAvailable;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs<List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading>> (list) );
        }
    }

    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        this.ReadingAvailable +=Program_ReadingAvailable;
        bw.DoWork +=bw_DoWork;

        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void Program_ReadingAvailable(object sender, EventArgs<List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading>> e)
    {
        List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> list = e.Value;

        // for each item in the list do something.
        foreach (var reading in list)
        {
            Logging.Log("Starting ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading 3", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
            var gpsreading = new TruckGpsReading();
            gpsreading.DateTimeOfReading = reading.DateTimeOfReading;
            gpsreading.Direction = reading.Direction;
            gpsreading.DriverNumber = CurrentIniSettings.DriverNumber;
            gpsreading.Latitude = (float)reading.Latitude;
            gpsreading.Longitude = (float)reading.Longitude;
            gpsreading.Speed = reading.Speed;
            gpsreading.TruckNumber = CurrentIniSettings.TruckNumber;
            gpsreadings.Add(gpsreading);
        }

        var response = client.SaveGpsReadings(globalSetting.TokenId, globalSetting.SourceId, gpsreadings.ToArray());
        if (response != "true")
        {
            Logging.Log("ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading: " + response, "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
        }
        else
        {
            Logging.Log("ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading: Reading.DeleteGpsReadings(readings)", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
            SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading.DeleteGpsReadings(readings);
        }
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // if there is something to read
        IEnumerable<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> readings = Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList();
        if (readings.Count() > 0)
        {
            OnReadingAvailable(readings);
        }
    }
}

public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    private readonly T m_value;

    protected EventArgs()
        : base()
    {
        m_value = default(T);
    }

    public EventArgs(T value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return m_value; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
IEnumerable<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> readings
```

do...

```
List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> readings
```

since you declare List instead of

```
var gpsreadings = new List<TruckGpsReading>();
```

explicitly do....

```
List<TruckGpsReading> gpsreadings =
```

then inside the method you do the work do this

```
List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> readings = Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList();
List<TruckGpsReading> gpsreadings = RecursionMethod(readings, new List<TruckGpsReading>());
```

then create the RecursionMethod....

```
private List<TruckGpsReading> RecursionMethod(List<SSS.ServicesConfig.data.Reading> first,List<TruckGpsReading> second)
        {
            if (first.Count == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in first)
                {
                    //do the work of adding that you where doing..
                    Logging.Log("Starting ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading 3", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
                    var gpsreading = new TruckGpsReading();
                    gpsreading.DateTimeOfReading = reading.DateTimeOfReading;
                    gpsreading.Direction = reading.Direction;
                    gpsreading.DriverNumber = CurrentIniSettings.DriverNumber;
                    gpsreading.Latitude = (float)reading.Latitude;
                    gpsreading.Longitude = (float)reading.Longitude;
                    gpsreading.Speed = reading.Speed;
                    gpsreading.TruckNumber = CurrentIniSettings.TruckNumber;
                    second.Add(gpsreading);
                    first.Remove(item);
                    //you need to break or you will get an invalidoperation exception
                    break;

                }

                RecursionMethod(first,second);
            }
            return second;
        }
```